How better to be compliant with OSS usage?
We use Apache libraries (hpttlclient, log4j) and few other OSS libraries which has difference license types.
What is the best way to attribute these libraires to be compliant with Foss?

Is it sufficient to use a Notice.txt and mention the usage of these libraries?
Anything else to take care ?

These applications are internal (company) usage.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If the applications are truly distributed only within one company, you don't need to do anything; a company is a legal person so there is no distribution, and the Apache conditions are only about distributing the program.

It's good practice to have a file like THIRDPARTY or THIRDPARTY.txt off the root folder of your source repo and also in your binary distribution, in which you list out all third party open source software by name, version, how (or where) are they used or linked, their copyright notice (if any), license SPDX identifier and URL to full license and/or full source repo.
At the beginning of this THIRDPARTY file, you can state something like:

Both the source and binary distributions of this software contain some
third party software. All the third party software included or linked
is redistributed under the terms and conditions of their original
licenses. These licenses are compatible with the [name of my
software's license] license that govern this software, for the
purposes they are being used.

Here is one example from SAP/openui5:

OpenUI5 includes the following subcomponents that are subject to
separate license terms. Your use of these subcomponents is subject to
the separate license terms applicable to each subcomponent. The full
text of all referenced licenses is appended at the end of this file.
Library: sap.ui.integration:
Component: UI5 Web Components, version: 1.7.0
Copyright: SAP
License: Apache-2.0
License Text: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/LICENSES/Apache-2.0.txt
Contained in: src/sap.ui.integration/src/sap/ui/integration/thirdparty/webcomponents/*
Component: Adaptive Cards, version: 2.9.0
Copyright: 2017 Microsoft
License: MIT
License Text: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/LICENSES/MIT.txt
Contained in: src/sap.ui.integration/src/sap/ui/integration/thirdparty/adaptivecards.js
src/sap.ui.integration/src/sap/ui/integration/schemas/adaptive-card.json
Library: sap.ui.webc.common:
Component: UI5 Web Components, version: 1.18.0
Copyright: SAP
License: Apache-2.0
License Text: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/LICENSES/Apache-2.0.txt
Contained in: src/sap.ui.webc.common/src/sap/ui/webc/common/thirdparty/base/.
src/sap.ui.webc.common/src/sap/ui/webc/common/thirdparty/theming/.
src/sap.ui.webc.common/src/sap/ui/webc/common/thirdparty/localization/.
src/sap.ui.webc.common/src/sap/ui/webc/common/thirdparty/icons/.
src/sap.ui.webc.common/src/sap/ui/webc/common/thirdparty/icons-tnt/.
src/sap.ui.webc.common/src/sap/ui/webc/common/thirdparty/icons-business-suite/.
Component: lit-html, version: 2.2.2
Copyright: Google LLC
License: BSD-3-Clause
License Text: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/LICENSES/BSD-3-Clause.txt
Contained in: src/sap.ui.webc.common/src/sap/ui/webc/common/thirdparty/lit-html/.

Here's another example from owncloud/android:

Both the source and binary distributions of this software contain some
third party software. All the third party software included or linked
is redistributed under the terms and conditions of their original
licenses. These licenses are compatible the GPL license that govern
this software, for the purposes they are being used.
The third party software included and used by this project is:

Transifex client.
Copyright (C) Transifex.
Licensed under GNU General Public License.
Placed at third_party/transifex-client.
Used as a helper tool, not included in the ownCloud client APK.
Original license document included at third_party/transifex-client/LICENSE.
See http://help.transifex.com/features/client/

floatingactionbutton 1.10.1.
Copyright (c) 2014 Jerzy Chalupski
Licensed under Apache License, Version 2.0.
placed at libs/com-getbase-floatingactionbutton-1-10-0-exploded-aar has been exploded by ownCloud GmbH.
See https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

PatternLockView, version 1.0.0
Copyright (C) 2017 aritraroy
Licensed under Apache License, Version 2.0.
Included in the ownCloud client APK.
See https://github.com/aritraroy/PatternLockView

Glide, version 4.6.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Google, Inc.
Licensed under BSD, part MIT and Apache 2.0.
Included in the ownCloud client APK.
See https://github.com/bumptech/glide



